# Mediawiki error empty response

Tags: apache, mediawiki

I install Mediawiki in my server following Tutorial, but sometimes ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE apper as error, without any apache error log message.

My Mediawiki version is 1.29.1

Comment: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE is typically an error shown by Chrome when there is a connection issue (i.e. nothing to do with any problem on your server, or with Mediawiki). As the issue is intermittent, is there any reason your connection may have been interrupted at those times?

Comment: It's true, but in some case I'm unable to edit all page of the wiki. I found that restarting apache the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE disapper, but I want to found where the problem is

Comment: In global apache log I found this error `zend_mm_heap corrupted`

Answer (score 0):

The Zend heap corrupted error can be solved in a few ways... in your case the most likely fix is to increase the value of `output_buffering` in your [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php) file.

Most other causes of this are at "the developer level", which if you are using Mediawiki is unlikely to be the problem.